# The correlation between the Residuals and the prediction $Cov(e,\hat{Y}) =0 $

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, linear-regression

assume a linear regression model: $y_i$ = $\beta_0$ + $\beta_1x_{i1}$..... + $\beta_px_{ip}$+ $\epsilon_i$

I'm asked to prove that:

$Cov(e,\hat{Y})$ = $0$

where: $e$ = the residuals vector

$\hat{Y}$ =  the predicted vector of Y

Hint: use the fact that $X^Te$ = $0$ (I already proved this fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your estimator: $$\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta}$$
Therefore, and by rules of Cov, you can take the constant matrix out (right side with transpose):
$$Cov(e, \hat{Y}) = Cov(e, X\hat{\beta}) = Cov(e, \hat{\beta})X^T$$
Now you can proove that:
$$Cov(e, \hat{\beta}) = 0$$

Since:
$$Cov(e, \hat{\beta}) = Cov(Y - \hat{Y}, \hat{\beta})= Cov(Y, \hat{\beta})-Cov(\hat{Y}, \hat{\beta})$$

1. $$Cov(Y, \hat{\beta}) = Cov(Y, (X^TX)^{-1}X^TY) = Cov(Y,Y)\times((X^TX)^{-1}X^T)^T = \sigma^2IX(X^TX)^{-1} = \sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}$$
2. $$Cov(\hat{Y}, \hat{\beta}) = Cov(X\hat{\beta}, \hat{\beta}) = X[Cov(\hat{\beta},\hat{\beta})] = X[\sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}] = \sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}$$

Therefore:
$$Cov(Y, \hat{\beta})-Cov(\hat{Y}, \hat{\beta}) = \sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}-\sigma^2X(X^TX)^{-1}=0$$

Both equations rely on knowledge about the distribution of $\hat{\beta}\sim N\big(\beta, \sigma^2(X^TX)^{-1}\big)$ and that $\hat{Y} = X\hat{\beta} = X(X^TX)^{-1}X^TY$